# QListView and QAbstractListModel: how to manually set an item under editing, with cursor flashing?

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, qabstractitemmodel

I have a `QAbstractListModel` and `QListView` (for example, a list of input ports of an electronic device).

I've just added a row into the model, gave it a temp name (something like `"RENAME_ME_PLZ_ASAP"`). I want user to rename it, and I want to set the editing focus to this cell to make it possible to start typing the new port name without aiming the mouse to the cell added and double-clicking on it.

The editing of the item should begin, and its temp text contents should be selected (to be deleted by user when the typing will start).

[image]

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

As you said you should should be able to edit, without aiming the mouse to the cell added and double-clicking on it.

Probably you can use `QAbstractItemView::CurrentChanged` edit trigger.

```
QListView *pListView = new QListView(<<Your parent widget>>); //rough
pListView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::CurrentChanged);
```

You have many edit triggers in below link, but I guess the above one suits you best.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#EditTrigger-enum

And if you are on embedded LINUX you can also use.

```
pListView->setEditFocus(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've just called `QAbstractItemModel::edit(...)` method.

^__^